# What is meant by Operator Specific Services (OSSs) in telecommunication?

Tags: telephony

Google search gives me definition of Value Added Services and other things, [but not OSS's](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=stackexchange%20networking&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=what%20are%20Operator%20Specific%20Services%20in%20telecom). I have read about OSS's [here](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=stackexchange%20networking&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=what%20are%20Operator%20Specific%20Services%20in%20telecom):

> The GSM service control function (gsmSCF) is a new entity that
>   consists of service logic for operator-specific services (OSSs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you might have encountered the term OSSs while going through the CAMEL procedure in GSM.

One point to note here is that the CAMEL feature is a network feature and not a supplementary service. It is a tool to help the network operator to
provide the subscribers with the operator specific services even when roaming outside the HPLMN(Home PLMN).

**OSSs is the set of services which are not covered by standardized GSM services**

The Services could be very specific to the particular Operator like Caller Tunes,IVR responses and any set of service provided by the operator which is not a standard one with respect to GSM standard.